# Running AWK in Vim's search

Tags: vim, awk

**How can you run AWK in Vim's selection of the search?**

My pseudo-code

```
%s/!awk '{ print $2 }'//d
```

I am trying to delete the given column in the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In command mode, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> to go into visual mode, then you can block-select the column using cursor movement keys. You can then yank and put it or delete it or whatever you need using the appropriate vim commands and keystrokes.

Answer (score 29):

Though they probably address the issue of the original poster, none of the answer addresses the issue advertised in the title of the question.  My proposal to remove the first line of the question and to retitle it as "Deleting one column in vim" having been unanimously rejected, here is a solution for people arriving there by actually looking for that.

Deleting a column (here the second one, as in OP's pseudocode example) with `awk` in `vim` :

```
:%!awk '{$2=""; print $0}'
```

Of course, it also works for a portion of the file — e.g. for lines 10 to 20 :

```
:10,20!awk '{$2=""; print $0}'
```

As for "[running] `awk` in `Vim`'s selection of the search", not sure you can exactly do that but anyway the search and substitution is an easy job for `awk`, if not its primary purpose.  The following replaces "pattern" with "betterpattern" in the second column if it matches :

```
:%!awk '$2~"pattern" {gsub("pattern","betterpattern",$2)}
```

Note that the `NOT` operator requires escaping (`\!` instead of `!`).  The following replaces the value in the second column by its increment by 10 if it matches "number" and let other lines unchanged :

```
:%!awk '$2~"number" {gsub($1,$1+10)} $2\!~"number" {print $0}'
```

Appart from this point it's just `awk` syntax.

Comment: I agree that the question should be renamed, or this answer voted the most correct one.

Answer (score 2):

You do not have to use awk, even if the second column is not a rectangular region. Use a substitution:

```
:%s/ \w\+ / /
```

The second column is made up of at least one from word characters (\w\+) separated by blanks. The replacement is one blank. This one is for a selected range of lines:

```
:'<,'>s/ \w\+ / /
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to delete something, use `:%s/pattern//`

pattern can't be a command, it's mostly a regular expression. expressing 2nd field in regular expression is not very easy

if you want to delete 2nd field, you can filter the text through cut utility

```
:%! cut -d ' ' -f 2 --complement
```

Answer (score -1):

you could press <kbd>0</kbd>, then press <kbd>w</kbd> to go to your 2nd column, and do <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>.

Answer (score -1):

You can delete a given column in a file just from vim.
In command mode use the following to delete column n:

```
:%s/\(.\{n-1}\).\{1}\(.*$\)/\1\2/g
```